# Why the address of "env" is different in the sequential function calls?

Tags: c, operating-system

```
void env_create(uint8_t *binary, enum EnvType type){
    struct Env *env = NULL;
    int r = env_alloc(&env, 0); // &env = 0xf0117fcc
    cprintf("env addr: %x\n", &env); // &env = 0xf0117fbc

    if(r != 0) panic("env_create：%e", r);

    load_icode(env, binary); // &env = 0xf0117fcc
    env->env_type = type;
}
```

When I use gdb to inspect the address of "env", it's always 0xf0117fcc, but the correct value of "env" after calling "env_alloc" is stored at 0xf0117fbc. I wonder what may cause the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proper way to print a pointer address is `%p` and not `%x`

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and tell us which command you use in gdb to _"inspect the address of "env"_

Answer (score 2):

env is an auto variable. In most, if not all, C++ implementations this is implemented on the stack. You're just getting a different stack location.